# NotMapped property still generates column in migrations

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have a model that maps to a table.
This model has a `Status` property.
This model also has an `Import` value object property that then has a bunch of its own properties that get mapped to columns in the model table.

I am trying to move the `Status` property into this value object, then replace the `Status` on the main model with a `[NotMapped] DisplayStatus` property that will be set manually based on the `Status` and some other values in the `Import` value object.
This status is an `ImportStatus DbEnum`.

When I generate the migration after adding the `[NotMapped] DisplayStatus` property the migration still creates the column and the foreign key to the `ImportStatus` table.

I've also tried adding `Ignore` to the `DbContext` `OnModelCreating method`:

```
b.Ignore(b => b.DisplayStatus);
```

This still does not fix anything.
If I start a new project from scratch I don't have this issue.

In case it is relevant the project was very recently upgraded from .net 5.0 to .net 6.0 and ef core was upgraded from 5.0.0 to 7.0.5. This is the first migration after that upgrade.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing was removing the `DbEnum` attribute from the enum. This entirely removed the table from the database and all columns that use this enum just store the integer value for the enum with no foreign keys. Entity Framework handles the conversions from numbers to enums.

It's now technically possible to update a value in the database to have a value that does not exist in the enum, which would've been prevented by a foreign key to the table. Other than losing this small amount of safety everything works as I would like.

If there's a way to include the enum in the database while also keeping my `NotMapped` property actually unmapped, then I'm all ears. But for now this works.